# How to test Excel workbook compatibility?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have prepared an excel workbook in Excel 2013 (32-bit) Windows.

It is a kind of report template, where others input the data, selects from in-cell dropdowns etc. The workbook does not contain any macros.

What is the best way to test the compatibility with the target audience, who mostly work on Excel 2007.

For example, in-cell dropdowns can have references from a separate sheet in Excel 2013, but these don't work in Excel 2007.

Do I need to install Excel 2007 on my system and test it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Compatibility checker` included in Microsoft Office, as of version 2007.

Further information can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Excel-2013-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-a1ed5fc0-c257-4d85-b342-73a30c65348c)

In Excel 2016 (Likely 2013 as well) this feature can be found under `File` -> `Info` -> `Check for issues` -> `Check Compatibility`

[image]

You should be greeted with a screen similar to the following:

[image]

This function can also be triggered by trying to save as an `Excel 97-2003 document .xls`

Answer (score 2):

From [Save an Excel 2013 workbook for compatibility with earlier versions of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Excel-2013-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-a1ed5fc0-c257-4d85-b342-73a30c65348c):

> Run the Compatibility Checker for Excel 2007 and 2010
>
> To verify that a workbook is compatible with Excel 2007 or 2010, run the Compatibility Checker manually the first time you save your workbook. Then set the Compatibility Checker to run automatically every time you save that workbook.
>
> 1. Click File > Info > Check for Issues.
> 2. Pick Check Compatibility.
> 3. To check for compatibility automatically from now on, check the Check compatibility when saving this workbook box.